# Kubernetes deploy failed with "Failed create pod sandbox" in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

While deploying a new deployment to our GKE cluster, the pod is created but is failing with the following error:

```
Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\"": unknown
```

The cluster is not loaded at all, and there is enough free disk, memory and CPU.

No other issue was seen in the pod/cluster logs.

Comment: do you have any memory request/limit defined on your deployment yaml !! if you could share more details of your deployment as well

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue was eventually in the deployment YAML.

If you encounter a similar issue, check your resources section and verify it has to correct syntax which can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

In my case, the issue was in the memory value:

**Working example (Note the Mi):**

```
resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 256Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 5m
      memory: 256Mi
```

**The initial resources definition (BAD SYNTAX):**

```
resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 256m
    requests:
      cpu: 5m
      memory: 256m
```

I hope that it'll help other community members in the future, since it took me a decent amount of time to find the root cause in my case...

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: @steve-k Glad I could help!

Comment: Your analysis helped me to fix the issue momentarily.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> **The RAM resource is measured in bytes**. You can express RAM as a plain integer or a fixed-point integer with one of **these suffixes : E, P, T, G, M, K, Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki**.

Refer [Memory Meaning on Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory)

> **CPU resources are defined in millicores**.
>   Fractional values are allowed and **you can use the suffix m to mean mili** when defining CPU limits. For example 100m cpu is 100 milicpu, and is the same as 0.1 cpu.

**Example** : If your container needs one full cores to run, you would put the value “1000m”. If your container only needs ¼ of a core, you would put a value of “250m”.